# return value remains undefined even when timed out for 10 seconds

Tags: javascript, mongodb, asynchronous, promise, settimeout

I had an issue where I needed to return the response of an async function which kept being returned as undefined. So I decided to use setTimeout() before trying to use it. It still doesn't seem to work. Can someone explain why?

My attempt:

```js
insertUser = (req,res) => {
    var record = {
        'handle': req.body.handle,
        'name': req.body.name,
        'password': req.body.password
    };
    var response;
    createUser(record, response)
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log(response);
    },10000)
};

createUser = (record, response) => {
    users.insertOne(record, function(err, result){
        if(err){
            response = {'code': 404, 'message': 'Something went wrong. Message: ', err} 
        }else{
            response = {'code': 200, 'message': result.insertedId}
        }
    })
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log(response)
    }, 1000);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `users.insertOne` doesn't run synchronously, and the function `createUser` returns before that, hence you are getting `undefined` as a return value.

There are a couple of ways you can solve this -

=> Using `async/await`

```
const createUser = async (record, response) => {
    try {
        const result = await users.insertOne(record);
        response = {
            'code': 200,
            'message': result.insertedId
        }
    } catch (err) {
        response = {
            'code': 404,
            'message': 'Something went wrong. Message: ',
            err
        }
    })
    
    return response;
};

const insertUser = async (req,res) => {
    let record = {
        'handle': req.body.handle,
        'name': req.body.name,
        'password': req.body.password
    };
    let response;
    response = await createUser(record, response);
    console.log(response);
};
```

=> Using plain promises

```
const createUser = (record) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        users.insertOne(record, function(err, result) {
            if (err) {
                // Or use `reject` if you want to have this in .catch callback
                resolve({
                    'code': 404,
                    'message': 'Something went wrong. Message: ',
                    err
                });
            } else {
                resolve({
                    'code': 200,
                    'message': result.insertedId
                });
            }
        })
    })
};

const insertUser = (req, res) => {
    const record = {
        'handle': req.body.handle,
        'name': req.body.name,
        'password': req.body.password
    };
    let response;
    createUser(record).then((res) => {
        response = res;
        console.log(response);
    });
};
```